# How to belongsToMany two keys and one via another relation

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, foreign-keys

sql scheme:

**users**

```
id (ai)
```

**bulletins**

```
id (ai)
owner = user.id
```

**conversations**

```
id (ai)
owner_id = user.id //UPDATED
bulletin_id = bulletins.id // this I can't get user ID(this is another 2nd user!) - don't know how.
```

**conversation model:**

```
public function bulletin()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Bulletins','bulletin_id');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','owner_id');
}
```

I need that **users()** return both relations

```
owner_id = user.id and bulletin_id->owner = user.id
```

and the same but in user model user->conversations:

```
public function conversations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Conversations::class,'owner_id');
}
```

here I need all conversations where owner_id or bulletin->owner = user.id

Comment: what is the difference between `owner_id = user.id` and `bulletin_id->owner = user.id`?
it seems both are same, `owner_id` is going to be a `bulletin owner`

Comment: no owner_id it's a conversation starter (buyer), bulletin_id->owner it's a bulletin owner (seller) - 2 interlocutors in one conversation

Comment: Ok, you want to get the user of a conversation or all the users matches this case `owner_id = user.id and bulletin_id->owner = user.id`

Comment: All users sure, owner_id I can get easy as you see it's already related in my code )

Comment: my mistake in first post show owner_id = bulletin->owner - it's not thruh - fixed it and update question - look at "//UPDATED"